# Unable to add an attachment to a PDF while using FOP

Tags: xml, pdf, apache-fop

I have an XSL document that transforms an XML document to a PDF. It had been working fine until I was asked to enhance this so that it is possible to add attachment to the PDF as well. I searched and found that the XSL must be edited in the following manner to achieve that.

1.The fo:root element should include **xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf** attribute.

2. Following piece of lines should be added before fo:page-sequence element.

**<    fo:declarations>

        <    pdf:embedded-file filename="    myfile.text    " src="    url(file:///C:/Bill.txt"    />

<    /fo:declarations>**

Now when I run the transformation I get the following error.

**Unknown formatting object "{http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf}embedded-file" encountered (a child of fo:declarations}. (No context info available)**

I searched a lot over the internet but could not find a solution to it. Can someone help me here ?

Comment: If I look up http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf on a browser I get an HTTP 404 return. Is that url correct ?

Comment: Even I got that error when I tried to open that link in the browser. But that was the instruction provided in the fop documentation which I found in their output.pdf document ( located under the <FOP_INSTALL_DIR>\\fop-1.1\docs\1.1 directory)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, your code fragment seems to respect the documentation for the extension element [pdf:embedded-file](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/output.html#pdf-embedded-file) (note that a namespace URI like http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf is just an identifier, it doesn't necessarily point to a web resource).

However, I tested this simple example with FOP 1.1 (by the way, you did not say which version of FOP you are using) and it works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="one">
            <fo:region-body />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:declarations>
      <pdf:embedded-file filename="test.png" description="This is just an image" src="https://www.google.it/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
    </fo:declarations>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block><fo:basic-link external-destination="url(embedded-file:test.png)">Attached image</fo:basic-link></fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**I was able to produce the error message you receive** (*Unknown formatting object ...*) **using an incorrect namespace URI**, for example adding a space at the beginning or at the end; so I suggest you check if your declaration of the pdf namespace is exactly like this:

```
xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf"
```

Comment: Works as intended with *Apache FOP 2.2* implementation.